# TypeError:object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I have following In a class definition of vb api. I need to use it in my python script

```
Public Property HideFilter( _ 
   ByVal FilterType As String _ 
) As String
```

I tried the following code in python scrip but its not working. Any help
CustUserGroup is object of the class

```
setattr(CustUserGroup.HideFilter, "FilterType ", "Req")
setattr(CustUserGroup ,"HideFilter", "FilterText")
```

Error : AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'FilterType '

```
CustUserGroup.HideFilter["Req"] = rfilter.Text
```

TypeError:object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear just what you are trying to do - but as a wild guess, you probably want something like

```
CustUserGroup.HideFilter = "Req"    # set property value

res = CustUserGroup.HideFilter      # get property value
```